# ruby gem not loading with RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

Ok so inside my Gemfile I have this gemspec

```
gem 'output', '0.1.0', git: 'ssh://git@git.company.com/pe/gem-output.git', tag: 'master'
```

When I run bundler install from RubyMine is says it was successful.
 but in my ruby code when I try to call `Output.write(message)` it says:

```
`message': uninitialized constant Pmt::Output (NameError)`
```

So then if I do a require 'output' at the top of my file I get this error message:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- output (LoadError)`
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you run `bundle install`? Are you executing your ruby using `bundle exec`?

Comment: I am doing everything through RubyMine. So I am going to Tools -> bundler -> install. I am not. I tried running the rb script by clicking the file in RubyMine and say run and I have also run it through terminal via ruby /path/file.rb with the same output

Comment: I just noticed that when I go to Languages -> Ruby SDK -> global(ruby-2.0.0-p643) I can see that certains gems have this path
Gem root: /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems
Gem root: /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/bundler/gems